# Strange symbol on Midwest brick home

Tags: united-states, identification

I am looking for help or guidance with something located on my parents 100  plus year old (we believe early 1900's, maybe earlier) brick home. They live in IL, just east of St. Louis, MO and have owned their home almost 30 years. We have never found out what a symbol on the outside of the house (where the chimney is) means. The symbol looks like a block lower-case "m" with the center leg of the "m" longer than the two side legs. And all of the legs end with crosses on them. Any information you can provide would be most helpful as my parents are thinking about downsizing soon and I would love to be able to answer this long standing question for them.

[image]

Comment: The photo would help (I removed your email address from the post - trust me, it's a spam vacuum).  If you upload it to an image sharing site or an online file sharing service you can post the link here and someone will edit it into the question.

Comment: Thank you! I made the picture I have my profile picture, so hopefully that helps, too!

Comment: Looks like an upside-down Golgotha, but it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: To whomever used the reason of trivia as a vote to close.... hah, I've wasted over 2 hours to no avail trying to find this symbol....

Comment: @CGCampbell some people just want to hit buttons…

Comment: I appreciate any help and my family and I have researched with no luck, too. I'm beginning to think that whoever had the house built last name began with an "M" and this is just a fancy way of showing it. We've never had any luck with another explanation. <sigh>

Comment: It is Masonic in nature. 3 crosses, 3 lines 33rd.....

Comment: Rather than searching for the symbol, have you tried to track down who the original builders were? They might have built something else…

Comment: @Lohoris - That's the exact first impression I got. Regardless of what it was *really* supposed to symbolize, I wouldn't be surprised to hear it caused trouble with the neighbors.

Comment: @Jessica did you look for the name of the original owner?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a stylisation in brick of the three golden globes of the pawn broker.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawnbroker

Comment: I'm not sure, why would they have used crosses, instead of squares?

Comment: Crosses are a good match for a 3x3 circle